# How to get the local listening ports in real time by C programming?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, kernel

I want to write a LINUX C application that can monitor the system TCP listening ports which provide web service. Whenever a new port is listened, or one port is released,  I can detect it in real time.
Does Linux provide system call to provide this feature? Or Should I hook the Kernel function?

Comment: Why can’t you use netstat instead?

Comment: `netstat` always hangs for a long time when too many tcp connection exist on system. And it's not a system call API.

Answer (score -3):

The code below will help you check if a port is open, if you need real time processing; you may continuously run the program in a separate thread.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int portno     = 22;
        char *hostname = "localhost;

        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct hostent *server;

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) {
            error("ERROR opening socket");
        }

        server = gethostbyname(hostname);

        if (server == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
             (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
             server->h_length);

        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
            printf("Port is closed");
        } else {
            printf("Port is active");
        }

        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The legal port ranges from 0 to 65535, if I make a loop to scan all these ports, or create too many threads to do the job, the performance will be a disaster to my server.

Comment: The best way is being informed when any port is listened. System hook is the best solution.